# In terms of appropriateness, do (since + past) and (since + perfect) have different meaning and usage?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

This problem is discussed in *Advanced Oxford Grammar* and the book explains that different tenses *are possible* in sentences with **since**. By the way, I quoted the explanations and some examples below:

> There may be a **past** tense in the **time expression** after
> **since**.
>
> > E.g. We've lived here since we got married [1].
>
> A **present perfect** is also possible in the time expression, to talk
> about **continuation** up to now.
>
> > E.g. We've lived here since we've been married [2].

As for my understanding after reading the information above, my first thinking was they are interchangeably used. However, the exercise in the book says otherwise. To illustrate this, I also provide the example taken from the exercise.

> We've all been eating much better since the new chef __ doing the
> cooking.
>
> > 1. has been (v)
> > 2. was (x)
> > 3. both (x)

The key answer tells that the answer is **has been**. This is where I'm starting to be confused. I mean, the explanations of the book I quoted above, in my opinion, imply that both **perfect** and **past** are possible. Then, how come the answer is not **both**?, meaning this sentence should be true?:

> We've all been eating much better since the new chef was doing the
> cooking.

P.S. The book doesn't tell the different usage.

Comment: Your initial examples [1] and [2] are word-for-word identical.  Did you mistype when transcribing them from the book?

Comment: @RichardWinters Edited. Thank you so much for pointing that out.

Comment: When they _got married_ was the start of their married life. To make a sentence comparable to (1), you would have to say "We've been eating much better since the new chef _started_ doing the cooking."

Comment: Excellent question, upvoted. People here don't appreciate good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be *has been*, because the time frame of the sentence is set by the verb *have ... been eating*.

The meaning with *have been eating* and *has been doing the cooking* is that both time periods coincide -we started eating well when he started cooking, and he still cooks and we still eat well.

The other answer *since the new chef did the cooking* isn't ungrammatical, but the meaning is very unlikely.

But you can change the meaning so that past tense makes sense:

> We've all been eating much better since *the new chef changed the menu*.